# Send a single byte over TCP socket python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to write a function in python 3.x that returns a single byte of data to send over a TCP connection.

The data I am trying to send is an `unsigned integer` from 0-100.

I am checking the bytes used by the data with `sys.getsizeof(data)`, but I have not come across an instance where `sys.getsizeof(data) == 1` .

lets say `data = 10`

I have tried several different ways to store a byte:

```
 1) struct.pack('>b', 10)

 2) bytes(10), bytes([10])

 3) 0x10

 4) bytearray(10)

 5) b'10'
```

all of these have returned over double digits in byte size.

I am looking for a way in python to send a single byte over a TCP socket.

Comment: If you only have a single byte, it doesn't matter if you have dozens of bytes of overhead, because you're only paying that overhead once. You have billions of bytes of memory.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Sure its not using those bytes, but I don't want the overhead because of space constraints.

Comment: Now, if you're calling this function more than once, so you have a *bunch* of bytes to store, then store them *together* in the same bytearray.

Comment: I only want to return a single byte

Comment: Python objects don't work like that. You can't just have a sigle byte, or a single machine integer, you always get a fully-fledged object, with the overhead that comes with that. Perhaps you should explain what you're really trying to do. For example, if you need to pass a byte from Python to a library written in C, then there's a way to do that.

Comment: I am trying to send that single byte over a TCP socket.

Comment: I agree with @Robᵩ, Python object will always have some overhead, I recommend this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is not like C or C++. Python inherently has high overhead. You can not store data in memory, but instead, get a fully-fledged object that is stored in memory.

When you try things like

```
 1) struct.pack('>b', 10)
 2) bytes(10), bytes([10])
 3) 0x10
 4) bytearray(10)
 5) b'10'
```

These are not storing bytes directly to memory, they are creating python objects to store byte data in. Thats why `sys.getsizeof(data) != 1`.

That being said there is a way around this to answer the underlying question. `socket.send()` requires a buffer or string and python has byte-strings. so  `socket.send('\x0a')` would send exactly one byte. You could also return a byte string from a function.

```
def return_byte_string():
    return b'\x0a'
```

Then this could be passed into `socket.send(return_byte_string())` to send a single byte over a TCP connection.

Answer (score 4):

Answering OP's underlying question:

> I am trying to send that single byte over a TCP socket.

The Python representation that you use to hold your byte is irrelevant. You don't send a copy of Python object, you send the value contained in the Python object. Since `socket.send()` requires a buffer or string, I'd have your function return a bytestring: `b'\x0a'` should work.

Here is a simple client program that sends exactly one byte to a server:

```
import socket

def return_one_byte():
    return b'\x10'

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost', 1234))
s.send(return_one_byte())
s.close()
```